# Is it possible to do a proper fork() in node.js?

Tags: node.js

My node.js application takes a few minutes to initialize and allocates significant amount of memory. And I would like to do some work in child processes.

The standard solution is to use the Cluster module, but this has two disadvantages:

- First, all initialization is repeated in children processes, wasting CPU memory;
- Second I'm losing huge copy-on-write memory saving provided by forking (the majority of allocated memory is only read).

I also looked at [child_process.fork](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) but it seem to do the same - i.e. it does fork+exec, which doesn't help me.

Standard Unix way is to do heavy initialization and then fork() after that. Is it possible to do with node.js?

Comment: There are some shared memory packages that might be helpful to you.  Depending on your needs, you might also considering writing a native extension, where you can fork or whatever you'd like while keeping most of your application in JS land.

Comment: Thank you Brad. I know I can write a native extension, but I'd rather reuse a standard one if there is one - or learn why it is not a good idea if there is no standard one.

Comment: I have a 2G of key-value pairs that need to be accessed quickly (i.e. in memory) across 72 different Node processes. I wrote the [mmap-object](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mmap-object) package to put the data into shared memory and avoid consuming 144G of core. It also initializes in an instant.

Comment: Unfortunately my initialization uses a 3rd party library and I can't control how it uses memory.